# Magento2: Intercept category moved inside tree

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin, category-tree, after-plugin

I am trying to intercept when a category is moved inside the category tree. At the beginning I thought to observe the event `catalog_category_tree_move_after` with an Observer class but I found that this event has been removed from Magento 2. In the `CHANGELOG` file it is said to use plugins instead of observers.

I tried to do with plugin with no success:
this is the `di.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category">
        <plugin name="MoveCategoryTree" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Category" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

this is the Vendor/Module/Model/plugin/Category.php class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

class Category
{
    public function afterCatalogCategoryTreeMove(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category, $result) {
        echo 'Testing...';
        exit();
    }
}
```

I tried also to rename the function `afterCatalogCategoryTreeMove` in `afterTreeMove` but nothing works also in this way.

is this the correct way to intercept this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this briefly and couldn't find the method you were trying to write a plugin for. The method `move` does exist and should be appropriate for what you're trying to do, try the code below instead:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

class Category
{
    public function afterMove(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $subject, $result) {
        echo 'Testing...';
        exit();
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!